# Is a spice model unique?

Tags: simulation, spice, model

i found an SPICE model for a component with diferent parameters than the ones that i found earlier (wich have the same parameters). So i am questioning wether there is a way in wich it is posible (and right) for a component with the same name (identifier code) to have diferent spice models with diferent parameters.

In case not, then the first one you stumble with when looking for a spice model on the internet is very likley the rigth and unique one, right?

Comment: Well I just opened up the bc547 model on my computer and randomly typed a bunch of numbers. Now there are at least two bc547 models: the standard one, and my one. One of them is more accurate....

Comment: Spice model for what? Two actual physical transistors of the same make and type may have very different characteristics so relying on the specific parameters of a particular Spice model is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Daniel, SPICE models are just that: models. There are often a great many parameterizations, with only a few of them important enough to worry over. So some folks just test one device and call it "good enough." Others will test a great many devices and develop a *mean value* as well as provide far more of the parameters where they aren't close to the default values. Some will even develop an entire .SUBCKT, instead, with all kinds of real-world parasitics added in where a model itself might otherwise be deficient. Who to trust? You'll have to look over the model, carefully, to judge.

Comment: If you look on the internet, \$\pi\$ is quoted in many different ways such as 22/7, 3.14159265359, 3.142 etc. and that's not counting mistakes made by people writing it down. That's a 0.04% spread in values and might be deemed unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're the furthest thing from being unique unless they're just copied.

In general SPICE models reflect typical characteristics, to some degree of accuracy. Datasheets offer 'typical' characteristics, sometimes, but the min/max is usually what we are most interested in.

A jellybean transistor eg. 2N3904 from manufacturer A may meet all the min/max JEDEC limits, but have different typical characteristics. Maybe they were actually designed as a somewhat better transistor and now they decided to package them as the lower performance part. Processes vary.

Sometimes models are optimized to run quickly at the expense of accuracy, because otherwise it would be difficult to run useful simulations.

Sometimes manufacturers have proprietary tricks that they feel might be compromised by revealing the entire model so they encrypt the model and unencrypted models are macromodels or just not available.

Sometimes the models are just not very good. Maybe a student or volunteer did it and released it to the wild.

Manufacturers have an interest in selling their products, so using a model the manufacturer you are planning on using has on their website is usually a good idea.

For example, as you probably know, the most important DC characteristic of a diode at low-ish currents is the forward saturation current Is in the SPICE model. You will find the number for a common part such as 1N4148 varies by 3:1 or more between different manufacturers. Since there is a ln in there, that's only about a +/-5% variation in Vf so it isn't as bad as it sounds. However you'll find also find it specified as eg. 4.352nA, to a silly number of decimal places, or to just one decimal place (eg. 7nA).

Depending *blindly* on the 'typical' characteristics, as described in the datasheet or in a SPICE model is a recipe for disaster. Design first then verify with simulation and prototyping. The typical characteristics can be useful in evaluating the limits and in understanding operation in a multi-dimensional space that is only guaranteed at a few points at best, that's why they're there, but one must take care.